# Accepting Payments in Android App

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing PayPal for payments in my android app. Everything is fine except that PayPal does not allow Indian customers to pay via credit card (REST API). India is a major market for us. Can anybody suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your merchant account is from other country instead of India, you could receive the payments from India Paypal accounts. (For US and UK merchants could apply the directly credit card payments in Paypal Mobile SDK.)